# Random variable $X$ inducing a distribution on $V$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, probability-distributions, random-variables

I have been learning about discrete probability and found a somehow confusing (to me) definition of distribution of a random variable $X$ on a set $V$.

The definition of a Random variable $X$: 
$$
X:U\to V
$$

Now, I'm reading that more generally, the Random variable $X$ induces a distribution on $V$ by the equation:
$$
P(X=v) = P\left[X^{-1}(v)\right]
$$

I imagine that $P(X=v)$ is the probability of $X$ being of value $v$.
So what does this $P\left[X^{-1}(v)\right]$ mean? How are both sides related? Is there a way of explaining it by example?

Comment: If $V$ is the (countable) set of possible values $X$ takes, then for all $v\in V$ we have $X^{-1}(\{v\}) = \{u\in U\mid X(u)=v\}$ an event (an element of our $\sigma$-algebra on $U$), since presumably, singletons are measurable sets in $V$ (as occurs for example when $V\subset\mathbb{R}$ is endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra). We can therefore find the probability of this event.

Answer (score 1):

The three following sets coincide:
$$
\{X=v\}=\{u\in U\mid X(u)=v\}=X^{-1}(\{v\}).
$$
In particular,
$$
P[X=v]=P[\{X=v\}]=P[X^{-1}(\{v\})].
$$

Answer (score 0):

$X^{-1}(\{v\})$ is the inverse image of the set $\{v\}$ under the function $X:U\to V$: $$X^{-1}(\{v\})=\{u\in U\,|\,X(u)=v\}.$$ In order words, $X^{-1}(\{v\})$ is the set of all points in $U$ for which the value of the function $X$ is $v$.

Answer (score 0):

$X$ is a function, and $X^{-1}(v)$ is the set of values in $u \in U$ that satisfy $X(u) = v$. So if you want to know the probability that $X = v$ where $X$ is considered a random variable (where the probability is denoted P(X = v) like you guessed), all you have to do is add up the probabilities of all $u \in U$ that satisfy $X(u) = v$. That's what the equation is saying.